# Write JavaScript in Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Firebug, I can type my own JavaScript in the console tab and execute it.  Is there a way to type JavaScript in Chrome Developer Tools and execute it?

Comment: Thanks.  I think I knew I could write a line there.  Is there a way I can write multiple lines of JavaScript?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

1. Go to `chrome://flags/`, enable the "Enable Developer Tools experiments" flag and restart Chrome (or start it with the `--enable-devtools-experiments` command-line flag.)
2. Open DevTools, go to the `Settings` dialog, switch to the `Experiments` tab.
3. Enable the "Snippets support" experiment, close and reopen DevTools.
4. Go to the `Sources` panel. In the left-hand navigator sidebar, switch to the `Snippets` tab .
5. Right-click in the [empty] tree in this tab, select the `New` context menu item.
6. Give the new snippet any name you like and type the snippet body.
7. Once done, click the `Run` (`>`) button in the status bar to execute the snippet body. You can set breakpoints in snippets and debug them as ordinary scripts.

Comment: Using Chromium Version 20.0.1132.47 Ubuntu 12.04 (144678), I found steps 2, 4, and 5 to be slightly different: 2) Open Developer Tools (`Tools` > `Developer Tools` - or `Shift + Ctrl + I`), click the settings icon (a small gear in the lower right), then *scroll down* to the `Experiments` section. 3 is the same. 4) Switch to the `Scripts` panel. Click the small tree-like icon if necessary. Now you'll see three tabs, `Scripts, `Content Scripts`, and `Snippets`. Switch to the `Snippets` tab. 5) Right click in the [empty] tree in this tab, select the `Create snippet` context menu item.

Comment: However, nothing seems to happen after I click `Create snippet`. Perhaps this is a bug with this version of Chromium.

Comment: How come you are still using Chromium 20? You should definitely update, as it has a lot of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I am surprised that Google makes it that hard to type JS in Dev Tools, but this worked.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov whoa! I didn't realize the official release was so far past this. 20 is the version available in the Ubuntu Software Center. I'll upgrade, thanks for alerting me to this.

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 30,and This Method is NOT WORKING.

Comment: As of August 2015, this feature is supported in the stable version

Comment: @etov Thanks for the note. However, I find that in Snippets there is no "intellisense" like in console.

Answer (score 22):

Step 1: Open Google chrome Dev tool [ **Press f12** ]

Step 2: Click on **Sources** tab

Step 3: On left side panel, Click on **Snippets** tab (may be hidden, if so click **>>** and it will appear)

Step 4: To create new snippet click **+ New snippet** or right-click within the Navigator, and then select **New**

Step 5: Develop your code into middle pane and save it.

Step 6: To run Snippet, there are three ways

```
       A: Ctrl + Enter

       B: Click on Run button [ Into Right-side panel, Top-Left button ]

       C: Right-click on the snippet filename (in the pane on the left that lists
          all your snippets) and select Run.
```

Answer (score 8):

**Recent Chrome**
Using Chrome 50, juste open the "Console" tab and start typing and executing your code at the bottom of the console.

Arrow up, recalls the code, ctrl-enter gives you a new line:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't debug Javascript, but you can execute it (including jquery) in a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) in the chrome inspector.

1. Open the inspector
2. Click the button at the bottom left with 3 lines - its tooltip is "show console"
3. Type your javascript and press enter

Note you usually have to go to the Sources tab and click the "pause script execution" button for your javascript to get evaluated.