# show console button disabled in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am unable to make the console bigger inside chrome. I remember I was able to do this a while ago. Is there a way to enable this ? The enlarged console would look like a firebug console where I can enter more than one line of code at a time.

[image]

Comment: You might want to check my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792553/write-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for, thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit `esc` to open the console and enable code entry once you have the dev tools open.

Comment: `shift + enter` to go to a new line