# Is there a way to make chrome developer tool's console more like that of Firebug console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have been using firebug for a long time. Thinking of switching to CDT. How can we enable multiline console like that in firebug with the ability to add breakpoints to the code on the console?

Comment: Chrome's console is multi-line...

Comment: Press Shift + Enter when making a new line.

Comment: thank you, is there a way to make the codes persist on the console even after execution just like in firebug command editor??

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792553/write-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools/13797341#13797341)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov That was exactly the thing I was searching for .

Comment: You can use Firebug lite, this will help for you! [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792553/write-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools