# How to auto align / indent code inside Chrome browser dev tools console?

Tags: console, google-chrome-devtools

I understand it may be possible in the "sources" tab, but how about the console tab? I find it supereasy to test stuff there, and quickly aligning / indenting code would be fab. Related answer for the sources tab:
[Write JavaScript in Chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792553/write-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: I use Snippets sub-panel for this. Ctrl-Enter runs current snippet.

Comment: Can you re-phrase what you mean by "quickly aligning code"? Do you mean highlighting a block of code, and then changing the indentation?

Comment: thx! rephrased it

Comment: The Console isn't really designed for typing large blocks of code. It's why you only see a single line input field. Snippets are recommended instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to auto-indent a selection of text in the Console.

The Console's built off of CodeMirror though, which does have support for that feature, so it's possible this could get added in the future. CodeMirror's keyboard shortcut for auto-indent is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

You can post to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-chrome-developer-tools) to request the feature.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/0nv5TF7_Ozw